# How to set activity layout based on user type / role?

Tags: android, database, firebase, user-interface, roles

I am working on an Android app with 2 types of users (doctors and patients), and I want each type to have their own UI. For eg, doctors must see ' Add days off' and patients must see ' Book appointment' . Somehow I don't get anywhere with whatever I try.

I also use Firebase Auth and Realtime Database which makes the user type retrieval kinda tricky. So far I've tried a lot of Async classes, methods, variables, shared preferences, retrieving data while on launcher splash screen.

The best I got is getting the user to login, it shows the good layout, then I start the app again and it shows the wrong layout. Somehow I noticed it just works on the second run, but not always so the behaviour is unpredictable to me at least. But at least the user type from the database is retrieved.

1. I have a class that extends Application, which checks if there's an user authenticated and then redirects the user to either LoginActivity, or MainMenuActivity.
2. I have created a method that retrieves the Firebase Auth user data from Realtime Database, looping through both Doctors and Patients 'children' until it finds the current user email and gets its type. Since Realtime Database is asynchronous, the methos gets an interface as an argument, and after the loop, the I call the interface's method, which sets a static boolean variable (isUserDoctor).
3. Before setting the content view (with 2 possible layouts), I call the function described before and it works the way I first mentioned, which is not good.

The method that retrives data

```
 public void getUserType(final DataStatus dataStatus) {

        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        currentUserEmail = currentUser.getEmail();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                currentUserType.clear();
                FirebaseManager.isUserDoctor = false;

                DataSnapshot allDoctors = dataSnapshot.child("Doctors");
                DataSnapshot allPatients = dataSnapshot.child("Patients");

                for (DataSnapshot ds : allDoctors.getChildren()) {

                    if (currentUserEmail.equals(Utils.decodeUserEmail(ds.getKey()))) {

                        currentUserType.add(ds.child("userType").getValue().toString());

                    } else {

                        for (DataSnapshot dsPacient : allPatients.getChildren()) {
                            if (currentUserEmail.equals(Utils.decodeUserEmail(dsPacient.getKey()))) {
                                currentUserType.add(dsPacient.child("userType").getValue().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(currentUserType.get(0).toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The interface

```
public interface DataStatus {

    void DataIsLoaded(String userType);

}
```

The method's call in Main Menu

```
FirebaseManager.getInstance().getUserType(new DataStatus() {
            @Override
            public void DataIsLoaded(String userType) {
                if ("doctor".equals(userType))
                    FirebaseManager.isUserDoctor = true;
                else
                    FirebaseManager.isUserDoctor = false;
            }
        });


        if (FirebaseManager.isUserDoctor)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_doctor);
        else
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
```

So if anyone has any ideas about how to show the proper layout and allow functions based on user role/type please share. What I basically need is to retrieve the userType from the current email just in time to set a variable needed throughout the whole app in order to hide/show certain views.